# How can I use NumPy in IronPython for Revit API?

Tags: numpy, ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I'm writing a script in Revit API by using python. I'm looking to use NumPy since I'm trying to generate a lattice grid of points to place families to. However, I know NumPy is not compatible with IronPython since it's written in CPython. Is there a solution for this? If not, is there any good way to generate a lattice grid of points without using external packages like NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyRevit has a [CPython engine available](https://ein.sh/pyRevit/pyrevit/updates/cpython/2019/02/16/47beta.html).
The post I linked was the beta announcement. It is now available in pyRevit master release.
Some people have already sucessfully used pandas and numpy.
pyRevit use [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)